# Binning values of columns (features) in scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, binning

Let's say I have a training dataset including the following rows (couple of samples from the dataset):

```
X1     X2      X3      Y
1      44.9    44.9    32.49370277
8      402.4   1       28.79444926
2      19.1    14      21.89679219
1      -26.3   11.3    20.36124795
1      -19.4   9.2     18.72667562
2      4.1     2.1     16.93972179
0      -1.2    1.2     16.59192825
1      3.4     3.4     16.43835616
3      7.8     4.6     16.35924841
```

where I have three variables (X1 to X3) as my features and a target variable (Y). When I train a model on the dataset (which includes more than 10,000 samples) I find not a strong correlation among these features.

Now, I want to group the values in each column (X1, X2, and X3) and see if it is going to affect the result of my model. I am wondering if there is any function that does that in sklearn? A function/method which bins/groups the values of each column and also gives me a combination of all the possible binning of these three features (X1 to X3) so that I can test them all and find the best model.

I noticed there is a function named **KBinsDiscretizer** in sklearn for binning, is this something I should use for the purpose of what I mentioned? And if yes, how should I choose the number of bins? Basically I am wondering if "**binning**" is the keyword that I should be looking for in order to group the values of features in the dataset for training models? Values could be either continuous or discrete.

If there is any other library/package in python that could do what I described, that would be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way, decide you custom boundary on which you want to bucket the variable.

```
bins_boundary = [0,1,2,8]
labels = ['A','B','C'] #labels
#CREATE BUCKETS
df['x1'] = pd.cut(df['x1'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
```

Continuous variables are bin to buckets for various purposes. Sometime you want to turn your regression problem into classification.

Also look at pandas **`qcut`** for effective discretization. You can also create bins using **`quantiles`** and population distribution of your variable.